# Can I run 32 bit laser engraver printer driver on 64 Bit OS?

Tags: 64-bit, upgrade, 32-bit

I work at a small trophy shop and we are wanting to upgrade our computer. One of my engravers must be run on 32 Bit OS. Is it possible to run a 32 bit printer driver on a 64 bit OS?

Comment: What you want is not possible. I highly suggestion you request 64-bit drivers or use a 32-bit operating system. All versions of license grant you the right to either a 64-bit installation or 32-bit installation. So if a computer comes with 64-bit you have the right, to format the hdd, and install the 32-bit version of that operating system instead.

Answer (score 2):

No, 64-bit (Windows, Linux, OS X) will only load 64-bit drivers.

The major OSs (Windows, OS X, Linux) can load a 32-bit *application* on a 64-bit version of the OS through the use of special abstraction layers that translate the 32-bit calls into their 64-bit equivalents, but this is not available for drivers.

Comment: As for the reason its not possible with drivers has to deal with how the operating system communicates with the hardware itself.